# react, how to not mutate state without deepcloning?

Tags: reactjs, formik, immer.js

You have data stored in a state (possibly redux state)

and You are using formik to modify your data.

In code,

```
 let { data } = props // from redux state

 // suppose data is somewhat deep like



   // data = {
   //   p1: {
   //     p11: {
   //     },
   //     p12: [{
   //       p122
   //     }, {
   //       p123
   //     }]
   //   },
   //   p2
   // }


   const handleSubmit = (values) => {

     dispatch({
       type: 'setData',
       payload: {
         data: values
       }
     })
   })

 <Formik initialValues={_.cloneDeep(data)} enableReinitialize onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
```

// reducer looks like

```
const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
  return produce(state, (draft) => {
     if (action.type === 'setData') {
         draft.data = action.payload.data
     }
  })
}
```

notice I'm cloning `data` with `_.cloneDeep(data)` to prevent mutating the state.
When data is flat, it's safe to get away with `{...data}` but when data are deep (have objects that have objects) it's not that easy

Is there an alternative way than deep cloning? 
I was wondering if `immer.js` could help here.

Comment: How does your reducer look like? That is the part of your code to make sure that you aren't directly mutating your state

Comment: my reducer uses immer.js and not mutating the data, but I still have to clone the data here because otherwise I would be mutating the state directly.

Comment: updated the reducer part @wentjun

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question as it is unclear why you need the deepClone in the first place, unless your reducer has side effects and mutates the payload rather than the state. In that case you can call `produce` on the payload data as well, for example:

```js
const reducer = (state={}, action) => {
  return produce(state, (draft) => {
     if (action.type === 'setData') {
         const dataToStore = produce(action.payload, payloadDraft => {
             payloadDraft.name = payloadDraft.name.toUpperCase()
         })
         draft.data = dataToStore
     }
  })
}
```